# Running functions that were declared outside my shell script

Tags: shell-script, zsh

Currently my ZSH has some sourced functions, for instance:

```
% declare -f
     ... a lot of shell functions appears here.
```

I'm currently writing a shell script that will call a specific function from that list (`prompt_dir` from Powerlevel9k's theme for Oh-My-Zsh).

My script is:

```
#!/bin/zsh
echo_prompt_segment(){
    # bunch of source-code here
}

zsh_oddeven_dir(){
   prompt_dir echo
}

zsh_oddeven_dir
```

Problem is that my script cannot access these functions:

```
% ./oddeven-pwd.sh
zsh_oddeven_dir:1: command not found: prompt_dir
```

When I do `declare -f` from inside the script, there are only those two functions that's inside my script:

```
% ./oddeven-pwd.sh 
echo_prompt_segment () {

}
zsh_oddeven_dir () {
    declare -f
}
```

Can I access and run those functions that were declared above my script? If so, how?

Comment: Please, do not add a solution to the question body. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) in the answer field. The text of your solution is still available [here](https://superuser.com/revisions/1328518/2) so you don't need to retype. Also adding "SOLVED" to the title is not what we do on Super User. Accepting an answer is enough to indicate the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since by default scripts run in subshells, the facility you require is exported functions, available in `bash`, but not in `zsh`.

In `bash` the standard place to add user functions is in `~/.bashrc`, but this is not executed unless `bash` is interactive (specifically, not in a subshell running a script), which exported functions overcome.

What does seem to work, as per [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406781/293940), is to put your function declarations in `~/.zshenv`, which is executed by default on every launch, interactive or not.

You should also look at the previous (accepted) answer, which among other things explains the reason that `zsh` does not support exported functions.

Comment: Well, the previous accepted answer directed me by actually seeing the actual problem: independently of `bash` or `zsh` (actually either my script and the function declaration were in `zsh`), when I run my script, it runs in a separated shell process, so it loses function references.
I solved the problem using `source myscript.sh` instead of normally running it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made the point that scripts by default run in subshells. I am so used to the idea that I forget that not everyone is aware of it. I have expanded my answer to explain this, with some salient points about how shells are initialised